# UglifyJS2 thows parse error (Unexpected token: name (Abide)) everytime

Tags: javascript, concatenation, uglifyjs2

I try to use uglifyJS2 to concatenate all JavaScript files (from ZURB Foundation 6 including some custom ones) into one single file.

In an upcoming project I can't simply use ZURB's Yeti Launch application. So I plan to use both sass for `scss` files (works already) and `uglifyjs2` for JavaScript files over command line.

Unfortunately I can't get uglifyjs2 to concatenate the scripts by fire the following command in command line:

`uglifyjs foundation-sites/js/*.js -o foundation-stes/dist/foundation.min.js`

It throws the following error even if I input only one single file (like [foundation.abide.js](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.abide.js)):

`Parse error at foundation-sites/js/foundation.abide.js:10,6
Unexpected token: name (Abide)
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2026:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2034:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2040:9)
    at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2060:56)
    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2240:73)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2113:19)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2073:24)
    at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2353:20)`

But if I write some basic scripts it works perfectly. **Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is anybody able to hive me a helpful hint?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to transform `ES6` to `ES5` before using uglifyjs. At the moment uglifyjs does not support `ES6` syntax. You can use `babel` for it. See more https://babeljs.io/.